# Parsing JSON response from a http request?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, httprequest

I'm using the 'requestify' module, from my Nodejs app, to make a http request to a site and return the html in a JSON format. However, I'm trying to use the JSON.parse() function but it doesn't seem to be working?

I've console logged the response to check the request is working, which it is..but the parsing isn't returning anything?

Any ideas? Code:

parse.js

```
    var requestify = require('requestify');
    var fs = require('fs')
    var obj;

    var url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk'
    requestify.request(url, {
                    method: 'GET',

                   cookies: {
                     'examplename':'examplevalue'
                    },

                  dataType: 'json'

    })
    .then(function(response){
     var pattern = /href=.{1,50}/g
     obj = JSON.parse('{"filter": "href.+/-", "flags": "g"}')
    obj.filter = new RegExp(obj.filter, obj.flags)
    var r = response.match(obj.filter)
    console.log(r)
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because the request specifies that you'd like json back does not mean that bbc will respond with json. It looks like bbc is responding with html, which makes `JSON.parse` failure expected.

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://www.bbc.co.uk -v > out.log
* About to connect() to www.bbc.co.uk port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 212.58.244.71... connected
* Connected to www.bbc.co.uk (212.58.244.71) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (universal-apple-darwin10.0) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8y zlib/1.2.3
> Host: www.bbc.co.uk
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< ETag: W/"2266d-K1zKA7z5pAya6M49nLj/pg"
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< x-origin-route: xrt-lb
< Content-Length: 140909
< Date: Sun, 10 Jan 2016 13:06:27 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: BBC-UID=c566b912a5f755d32356f02df1d767d43a09776757d42496ea40c7c28dc4415c0curl/7.19.7%20(universal-apple-darwin10.0)%20libcurl/7.19.7%20OpenSSL/0.9.8y%20zlib/1.2.3; expires=Thu, 09-Jan-20 13:06:27 GMT; path=/; domain=.bbc.co.uk
< X-Cache-Action: HIT
< X-Cache-Hits: 123
< X-Cache-Age: 9
< Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Vary: Accept-Encoding, X-CDN
```

Comment: Whats the best way to convert the html to JSON?

Comment: Extracting data from html could be done with a library like https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio